How do you move a NavMeshAgent via RigidBody?
I have a very basic character that can be played by the player and by the AI. I use a RigidBody for the movement, but the AI needs to use Unity's NavMeshAgent to do pathfinding, but I don't want to use the NavMeshAgent's movement, since I want it to be a 1-to-1 with the Player's movement speed and acceleration and physics interactions. I have searched Google and YouTube and StackOverflow and even asked ChatGPT many times and can't find anything that explains how to do this.
ChatGPT's answers are simply false. It always suggests setting NavMeshAgent.updatePosition and updateRotation to false, but that seems to decouple the NavMeshAgent's position from the RigidBodies, resulting in completely broken movement. (Ie, the player seems to get stuck on walls while the NavMeshAgent moves perfectly through the level.
The closest YouTube answer I found on YouTube uses Animation RootMotion but involves setting the speed, angular speed, and acceleration to 0, which results in a "desiredVelocity" of zero, so I can't even get a direction to apply the force, and every other video I've found is a no-sound "demo" that only shows it in action with no explanation of how.
How do you get the RigidBody to move along the path of the NavMeshAgent without getting stuck on everything?

if you dont want to move via navmesh - why even have it? however, ive never had issues with the rigidbody on my navmesh agents becoming separated or stuck on things that they shouldnt..

@BugFinder I want the AI to use the pathfinding from Navmesh so it knows what directional input to apply so it emulates a player using the movement input, that way the movement physics is identical to a player.
